# run php script periodically with interval time using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, setinterval, scheduler

Is there anyway to run php script periodically using JavaScript?
I have tried several event and timing in JavaScript but I'm still not satisfied.
I have created a php file to retrieve a json file from an url.
Now I want to run my php file every interval time that users set in input.

My form has the following properies:

uri
start
Finish
Interval

Here is my php code:

```
function toCsv(){
    //Date Format
    $date=date("M-d-Y, \a\\t g.i a", time());
    //URI API Endpoint
    //$uri="https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/t2qc-9pjd.json";
    $uri= $_POST['input_uri'];
    //Time interval
    $interval= $_POST['set_timer'];
    //Named File
    $file_name= $_POST['file_name'];
    //Get File JSON
    $json=file_get_contents($uri);

    $filecsv = fopen("dataset/csv/dataset-".$file_name."-".$date.".csv", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    $firstLineKeys = false;
    foreach ($array as $line)
    {
        if (empty($firstLineKeys))
        {
            $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line);
            fputcsv($filecsv, $firstLineKeys);
            $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
        }

        fputcsv($filecsv, array_merge($firstLineKeys, $line));
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your only options are to create a file and access it using ajax OR to refresh the entire page/an hidden iframe with the php file every x seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a setInterval and run an ajax request (every 5sec in the example)

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.post('1.php?', {input_uri:"value", set_timer:"value", file_name:"value"}, 
    function(data){            
      //do something with the information returned from the php file
    }, 'html')
   }, 5000);
```

You should replace "value" with the actual value of your input field (like `input_uri:$("#input_uri").val(),`

Answer (score 0):

what about...

```
function getJSON(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $.post( "YOUR PHP FILE NAME", {input_uri : "//form data", file_name : "//form data" } )
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert("php function ran");
        });
        getJSON();
    }, 3000); // Edit this timing here to set the interval (milliseconds)
}
```

and in your php file you just need to make sure you run your function at the bottom...

```
        fputcsv($filecsv, array_merge($firstLineKeys, $line));
    }    
}

toCsv();
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another easy method is to do this, on your main page:

```
<iframe src="csv_file.php?input_uri=value[...]" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

And on your `csv_file.php` you add this line at the end:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Being `5` the number of seconds to refresh.

This method doesn't require **any** javascript and works on most of the web-browsers (except text-only browsers and browsers with disabled iframes).

---

In case the user needs to edit the value, one can send the form (on whichever way it is being sent) and add a parameter.

For simplicity, one could call it `refresh`.
An example using the parameter:

You use this in your main page:

```
<iframe src="csv_file.php?input_uri=value[...]&refresh=5" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

On the `csv_file.php`, you use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['refresh']) && ($_REQUEST['refresh']=(int)$_REQUEST['refresh'])?$_REQUEST['refresh']:'5'; ?>">
```

Comment: but i want the users set the time interval, uri and when it finished as given in a form.

Comment: @HendrikTampubolon In that case, you edit the src attribute (using php or javascript) to have  a new parameter. The next refresh will take that `x` seconds or you can force it to refresh with javascript.